# How to create a Div with follow and stopping at the footer? - jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I used this tutorial:  http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

I came out with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version <7;

if (!msie6) {

var top = $('#right-sponsor').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function()
      {

  var y = $(window).scrollTop();

  if(y >= top){
    $('#right-sponsor').addClass('fixed');
           }
  else     {
    $('#right-sponsor').removeClass('fixed');
           }

      });

  }
});
```

The tutorial suggested putting the div I want to move into another "wrapper div" to make the transition smooth, here is the css I'm using.

```
#sponsorWrapper {
  position:absolute;top:215px;right:5px;
  width:232px;
}

 #right-sponsor{
   position:absolute;top:0px;
   padding:2px 10px 10px 10px;
   width:215px;
   margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  }

 #right-sponsor.fixed{
    position:fixed;top:0;
  }
```

It works Great!

But.... when it gets down to the bottom of the page it overlaps my footer. How do I account for that? I'm guessing that I need to set some type of Ymax value, when it hits the Ymax it will stop? But, I'm not really sure how to do that. Anybody know or know of a tutorial to explain.  I don't know jquery much at all.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use jQuery's .height() function to determine the height of your container. Then subtract the height of your menu and base your Ymax value off of that.

```
var heightOfMenu = $('#right-sponsor.fixed').height();
var ymax = $('#float_container').height() - heightOfMenu;
```

You'll want to modify this a bit to suit your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the wrapper of your element doesnt overlap the footer you can try the following:

```
var maxY = $('#right-sponsor').parent().height() - $('#right-sponsor').outerHeight();
```

Then at the end of your `scroll` event function add:

```
if(y > maxY) {
    $('#right-sponsor').removeClass('fixed');
}
```

Comment: if I do that, wouldn't my Div "jump" all the way back up to the initial position.  What if I want the div to stop at the footer, staying fixed then, follow me back up to the top of the page?

Comment: I would just use marginTop and set that to the scroll instead of removing and applying a fixed position.